# "cognitive" meaning in simple words?

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary, terminology

What is the meaning of "cognitive" ?in simple words? Does it means,ability to memorize or ability to learn or any other meaning?

Answer (score 1):

Cognitive is the adjective form of cognition, which Wikipedia defines as *the mental action or process of acquiring knowledge and understanding through thought, experience, and the senses*.  In even simpler words I would (personally) say it mostly relates to thinking.  I would say that learning and memorization would both count as cognitive activities although cognition is broader than either of those abilities.

Comment: you mean,it is simply ability "to think or to ponder"